# What does RC stand for in the context of multithreading/multiprocessing?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I saw people frequently use the variable name `RC` or `rc` when working with multithreading, for example in [this Linux `pthread_setname_np` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html), there is:

`rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);`

What does RC stand for in this context?

My suspicion is that it means "return code", but I didn't find an authoritative source to verify that.

Comment: i believe you are right. `pthread_create` returns error code, so that's could be *return code*.

Answer (score 3):

yes, good guess, RC or rc is commonly used variable name for having return value
from API in programming.

but that is just local variable of the return type of the API, other commonly used is ret_code but is matter of choice to name return value of the API. I don't think some document exist to explain why this RC naming came to existence :-)

Answer (score 1):

You won't have *authoritative* sources explaining that. People name their [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) as they like (provided there is no conflict with something else in the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) or with keywords).

But your guess (`rc` for "return code") could be a good one.

However, the equivalent code `int i = pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, threadfunc, nullptr);` might be considered as readable as your example. Personally I tend to name such local variables `int err = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);` in my C code.

PS. The use of  `NULL` and `pthread_create` suggests a C program using [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (see [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)), not a C++ one. In genuine modern C++11 you'll better use [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) and [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead (even if most implementations would indeed implement it above  [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html))

Comment: C++ places high value on backwards compatibility, so C++ code using `NULL` and calling C APIs is just as "genuine" as C++ code calling using `nullptr` and `std::thread`.  Perhaps "modern C++" would be a better term for it.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that RC stands for Reference Counter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).